# Ab initio MD simulations in VASP

Tags: computational-chemistry, software, density-functional-theory

I'm not sure if this is an appropriate question for Chemistry.SE, but I'm taking a stab. I'm running ab initio MD calculations in VASP and I'm trying to optimize different input tags. On the [VASP website](https://cms.mpi.univie.ac.at/vasp/vasp/Molecular_Dynamics.html), it says that the MAXMIX tag should be set to at least 3 times as large as the number of electronic iterations required to converge the first step. I tried doing this, but I didn't see any speed up and instead a significant slow down. I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered this issue.

The system that I'm simulating is a silicon supercell in contact with water.

Comment: This site seems to be more up to date and detailed. https://cms.mpi.univie.ac.at/wiki/index.php/MAXMIX . Based on what they say here, it seems like getting a speed up from this setting is relatively system dependent (I have never used VASP so take this with a big grain of salt). It may help users who know more about VASP to have a better sense of what your system is.

Comment: @Tyberius Thank you. I suppose you are right, I can't think of any other reason. Thanks!